# Question about triangle inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

By factoring $z^4-4z^2+3$ into two quadratic factors an using the triangle inequality, show that if $z$ lies on the circle $|z|=2$ ($z$ is a complex number) then

$$\left|\frac{1}{z^4-4z^2+3}\right| \leq 1/3$$

Approach: I am still trying to figure out how to factor the given polynomial into two factors. Maybe we don't have to and we have to use the fact that $|z^4-4z^2+3| \leq |z^4+4z^2+3|$

I don't know to be honest. How can I approach this?

Comment: I think you got a typo on your answer

Answer (score 0):

$$ z^4 - 4z^2 + 3 = (z^2 - 3)(z^2 - 1). $$
$$ \lvert z^4 - 4z^2 + 3 \rvert = \lvert z^2 - 3 \rvert \lvert z^2 - 1 \rvert \ge (\lvert z^2 \rvert - 3)(\lvert z^2 \rvert - 1) = ({\lvert z \rvert}^2 - 3)({\lvert z \rvert}^2 - 1) = (4-3)(4-1) = 3 $$ which proves the result after rearranging.

Comment: how did you replace 4 by $|z|^2$ at the end?

Comment: I am still trying to understand how you got $|z^2-3||z^2-1| \geq (|z^2|-3)(|z^2|-1)$

Comment: The reverse triangle inequality:
$\lvert a - b \rvert \ge \lvert a \rvert - \lvert b \rvert$

Comment: This can be derived as follows: $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert (a-b) + b \rvert \le \lvert a-b \rvert + \lvert b \rvert \implies \lvert a - b \rvert \ge \lvert a \rvert - \lvert b \rvert$

Answer (score 0):

Factor the polynomial as: $(z^2-3)(z^2-1)$. You can think of it as factoring the polynomial $x^2-4x+3$ and taking $x = z^2$. Then you can do:

$$\left|\frac{1}{(z^2-3)(z^2-1)}\right| = \frac{1}{|z^2-3||z^2-1|} \leq \frac{1}{||z^2|-3|||z^2|-1||} \leq $$

$$\frac{1}{(||z|^2-3|)(||z|^2-1|)} \leq \frac{1}{(4-3)(4-1)} = \frac{1}{3}$$